# A specific question about regular expression related to fixed width negative look-behind

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regular expression (for use in Java, if that is important) that attempts to match the number (could be a float) after a $ (allows spaced between the $ and the number), but only if the word immediately preceding it is not the word 'LOST'.

If there are multiple possible matches, the first number should be returned.

For simplicity, assume all are upper-case.

For example, in the following sentence: "I PAID $10.12 FOR THE BEER", 10.12 will be matched. For the sentence "I LOST $11.34 IN THE GAME", there will not be a match. For "I LOST $11.34 IN THE GAME AND PAID $10.12 FOR THE BEER", 10.12 will still be matched.

The regular expression I come up with is

```
.*?(?<!LOST )[$]\s*(?<NUMBER>[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*).*
```

My regular expression generally works fine, though I wonder if there is an easier way to write it/if I am missing any corner case. One slight issue is if there is more than 1 white-space between LOST and $, I still do not want to match but currently my regular expression will match. Unfortunately, negative look-behind have to have fixed width.

Clarification: To clarify, when I say "the word immediately preceding it is not the word 'LOST'", I meant that before '$' there cannot be 'LOST\s*'. This means that both 'LOST $123' and 'LOST    $123' should not match 123, but 'LOST! $123' can match 123. The rationale is that the currency should not be directly 'acted on' by LOST; if there is anything other than \s between LOST and $, then there is a good chance the currency is not directly 'acted on' by LOST.

Comment: Can't you just collapse all sequences of whitespaces into one single space first?

Comment: Another idea is to match `\s*` normally, find the next position left to `$` that is not preceded by a whitespace with use of another lookbehind `(?<!\s)` and put your current lookbehind there: [`(?<!\s)(?<!\bLOST)\s*\$(?<NUMBER>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/SoDbzs/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say there could be between one and 99 whitespaces between `"LOST"` and the dollar sign. I've also assumed the number has two decimal digits, and there are no commas that serve as thousands separators. Then one could attempt to match the string with the regular expression

```
(?<!\bLOST\s{1,99})\$(?<NUMBER>(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2})\b
```

If there were a match the capture group named `NUMBER` would contain the dollar amount of interest.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8J0Ou/1)

Hover the cursor over the regular expression at the link to obtain explanations of each element of the expression.

---

---

Another way is to attempt to match the regular expression

```
\bLOST\s+\$(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2}\b|\$(?<NUMBER>(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2})\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5R6tKu/1)

In this case pay no attention to matches that do not capture; only to ones that do, in which case the capture group `NUMBER` will contain the monetary value of interest. Here

```
\bLOST\s+\$(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2}\b
```

matches, but does not capture, values preceded by "LOST" followed by one or more whitespaces followed by a dollar sign. One might say it gobbles up such substrings.

Comment: I see that it works, though I don't understand the second method. The idea is to match a non-capturing group | a capturing group. If and after the non-capturing group is matched, why would the capturing group also be matched? In other words, let's say I have an re 'A|B', then if A is matched, there shouldn't be any attempt to match B right?

Comment: darkgbm, suppose the string were, `"I LOST  $11.34 IN THE GAME AND PAID $10.12 FOR THE BEER"`. The regex's pointer is initially at the beginning of the string, before `"I"`. The first part of the alternation does not match from that location so an attempt to match the second part of the alternation, and it does not match either. The string pointer is therefore advanced one position and is now between the `"I"` and a space. That does not match either, so the pointer is moved before the `"L"`. ..

Comment: ...`LOST  $11.34` is then matched by the first part of the alternation. Since nothing is capture we pay no attention to that match. The match causes the string pointer to be moved to the end of the match, between the `"4"` and the following space. The space is not not matched so the pointer is advanced one character and continues to be advanced until it is before the dollar sign. At that location the first part of the alternation does not match but the second part does, with `"10.12"` captured in group 1. That is the value of interest as it was captured. Make sense?...

Comment: ...As you see, the first part of the alternation matches the bits we don't want and the second part captures the bits we do want. You can read more about this technique [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). If you don't want to read the entire treatise you may wish to search for the section, "The Best Regex Trick Ever (at last!)".

Comment: I was thinking that maybe you might also shorten the matching to `\bLOST\h+\$|\$(?<NUMBER>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` or using the more specific matching for the numbers of course.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, good point. Readers: #4 is suggesting that in my second method the first part of the alternation (which does not capture) need match no farther than the dollar sign. (#4: do you know which may be more efficient?). He (I know it's a he from the colour of his feathers) also suggests using `\h` rather than `\s`, mainly to avoid matching newlines. I believe a *horizontal whitespace*, `\h`, is a tab or a Unicode space separator.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77154641/10289265), I propose this regex that may look cleaner and have wider edge case coverage:

```
(?:^|(?<!LOST)\b)\W*\$(?<NUMBER>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Because Java cannot have a non-fixed width lookbehind. The position where you put your lookbehind is crutial.

1. Since you don't want the word before the currency is `LOST`, you may match a word boundary first:

```
\b
```

2. Then you need to make sure that word is not `LOST`

```
(?<!LOST)\b
```

3. After that, put your currency match behind it preceded by optional non-word characters:

```
(?<!LOST)\b\W*\$(?<NUMBER>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

4. Then, add some edge cases such as the string starts with the currency:

```
(?:^|(?<!LOST)\b)\W*\$(?<NUMBER>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/tD7gWW/1)

Comment: Yes this handles edge case better than @blhsing's solution. For example, this solution would correctly handle '*$11.34 IN THE GAME AND PAID $10.12 FOR THE BEER'.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the answer so that 'LOST! $10.12' is a match? i.e. there is no match only if between LOST and $ there is only \s*.

Answer (score 3):

Since a lookbehind pattern has to be of fixed width in Java, you can allow a variable number of spaces by using a negative lookahead pattern instead to exclude the word `LOST`. Also include the beginning of a line with `^` in an alternation pattern in case a match occurs there:

```
(?:^|(?!LOST\b)\b\w+\s*)\$\s*(?<NUMBER>\d+\.\d+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/4pqyc0/7

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use a lookbehind here, but rather a capture group:

```java
String input = "I LOST $11.34 IN THE GAME AND PAID $10.12 FOR THE BEER";
String pattern = "\\bLOST \\$?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));  // 11.34
}
```

Comment: My intention is to avoid matching the number after 'LOST $', and there is no guarantee that 'LOST $' might come before or after a valid '$'. So this wouldn't work. Thanks for the answer though.